# POST issue with Node/Express

Tags: mysql, node.js, orm, sequelize.js, postman

I am trying to create a post route to my mysql database with the help of the ORM called sequelize. However, after writing my POST route, I tried running it in postman and it wasn't working. I feel like I wrote everything correctly though. Could someone help please?

Here is my controller file that contains the POST route

```
const db = require("../models");

module.exports = function(router) {

    router.get("/api/tasks", (req, res) => {
        db.Task.findAll({}).then(data => {
            res.json(data);
        });
    });

    router.post("api/task", (req, res) => {
        db.Task.create({
            task: "testing",
            completed: false
        }).then(data => {
            res.json(data)
        }).catch(err => res.json(err))
    })
}
```

Here is my sequelize model

```
const Sequelize = require("sequelize");

module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes){
    var Task = sequelize.define("Task", {
        id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        task: Sequelize.STRING(300),
        completed: {
            type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
            defaultValue: false
        }
    });
return Task;
}
```

Not sure if it is important but below is my migration file that created the table in the database

```
'use strict';

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.createTable("tasks", {
      id: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER(11),
            allowNull: false,
            autoIncrement: true,
            primaryKey: true
      },
      task: Sequelize.STRING(300),
      completed: {
          type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
          defaultValue: false
      },
      createdAt: Sequelize.DATE,
      updatedAt: Sequelize.DATE
    })
  },

  down: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    return queryInterface.dropTable("tasks");
  }
};
```

The error that came up was just "Cannot POST /api/task"

Comment: How are you calling the controller?

Comment: require("./controllers/taskController")(app);   inside of my server.js file.

The get request in the controller works fine so I believe it is linked properly

Comment: the leading slash is missing on the POST route, btw

Comment: you are missing the leading slash... classic typo

The design of your controller could be better though..

Comment: AHHHHHHH WOW that was the only problem hahahah thank you guys for catching that! I appreciate it :)

Comment: @1baga what do you suggest I can improve on for my controller?

Comment: @SamuelPai you could try to move all your business logic to a different file and just import the file and call each function with the parameters it needs... a whole lot more you can fix.. and please Async/Await... callbacks will disgrace you someday.. lol